# Plesk: Disable ability to decrypt mailbox passwords

Tags: encryption, password-protection, plesk

Plesk encrypt the Passwords and stores them in the mysql-psa-database but there is still the */usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mail_auth_view*-command which enable the admins to decrypt all customer passwords. (mailbox passwords)

Is there a option or a workaround to prevent this or better: disable the option that plesk can decrypt the passwords?

Comment: I'm using the latest plesk Version (Plesk Onyx 17.5.3) with CentOS 7.

Comment: Do you need the plain text passwords other than as a verifier? The usual and NIST recommended method of handling password verifiers is to the PBKDF2 but there are other acceptabvle methods such as `ehash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force and eliminate admins and attackers from obtaining the passwords.

Comment: The point is i don't want the ability to see the passwords of other users / customers. It isnt compatible with the german data protection.

Comment: Do you need the plain text passwords other than as a verifier? That is do you even need the actual passwords provided by the user or just need to verify an entered password is valid?

Comment: Yes, European, including German, laws protect the users, here in the US we protect the companies: anything goes, you can save them as plain text, sell them if you want.